# spatie/laravel-multitenancy how to access landlord database for CRUD purpose ? (Laravel 8)

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

I'm currently learning on how to implement a multitenancy application on Laravel using the spatie/multitenancy library.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy

I've read the documentation and I'm using a multi-database approach and watching tutorials on YouTube as well.

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/installation/using-multiple-databases

https://youtu.be/uvnvYzQ2fw0

In that tutorial, I only taught how to access the database for tenant-only, I managed to do that and kinda make a simple CRUD on the admin page. but what I want to know more how do I access the landlord database to do simple CRUD too (like register a new tenant, view table of tenants).

I've tried to find a solution on many forums and tutorials on YouTube, but none of them really provide a way of implementing it. I'm still in the learning process so please help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's all on the documentation page:

Executing code for tenants and landlords:
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/advanced-usage/executing-code-for-tenants-and-landlords

Preparing Models:
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/installation/using-multiple-databases#content-preparing-models

Since the default tenant model from the package uses the `UsesLandlordConnection` trait you should just be able to call: `Tenant::create(...);`

Comment: hello, could you give more example? cause i still doesn't understand on how to utilize the package to connect to landlord database